# Best way to use a proxy to call external API

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

I am building an application in node.js running on an EC2 server that allows people to input their API keys to a particular service, and I call this API on their behalf and present the data in a dashboard.

The API provider I use is relatively new and they put in place an IP address rate limiter. I contacted them to explain I needed to call the API for multiple people at once hence making it unsustainable to have my IP limited as I need to wait 1 to 2 seconds between calls, and there are a lot of calls to make, but they said they cannot whitelist my IP or make their rate limits based on API keys rather than IP, and suggested I try using proxies to request data from them.

I have tried multiple proxy providers but they are all very slow (request takes 1 second vs <100ms to reach my server), which makes this whole thing not sustainable once again.

Is there a smarter way to do this / easier way ? I do have a few other EC2 servers running so I was thinking of using them as proxy but I am not sure what that will do to the performance of these servers / the applications that are running on them already and it might create an issue if I were to terminate these servers (my application being reliant on them).

Is there any other best practice / easy way to do this?

For reference, my code looks like this:

```js
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
const proxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

const headers = {
   ...headers
   agent: new proxyAgent("<proxy details>")
}

const data = fetch("<url>", {headers: headers}) 
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out how to do this?